# In Android O, I need to know if the shortcut with known shortcutId is pinned or not. Is there any API for this?

Tags: android

There is an API to get all pinned shortcut.

List getPinnedShortcuts ()
Return all pinned shortcuts from the caller app.

But I need API for the given shortcut id if it is pinned to home screen or not.

Comment: I think that you need to iterate over that list and see if one of the `ShortcutInfo` objects has your ID.

Comment: I want to avoid this iteration. Therefore looking for any other better API.

Comment: First, I doubt that there is one. Second, the list is likely to be very short, as it is only your app's pinned shortcuts.